# Wordpress separate php file error

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my problem. 
I have created an admin page, where i display different list of data: 
example:

```
 echo '<div> <p><a href="http://example.com/admin-bar/request_data_by_query/change-request-data.php?id='.$name['id'].'" target="_blank">'. $name['name']. '</a></p> </div>';
```

The code below works fine on this page:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
     echo "You are viewing the theme";
} else {
     echo "You are viewing the WordPress Administration Panels";
}
```

It gives me the answer, because it see, that i am a user and i am admin.

As you can see at my href, i send a GET method data to file change-request-data.php.
In this file i get my GET id and display a form that has id=x.

```
<?php 
include "../../wp-load.php";    
global $wpdb;
$request_id_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM request_info where id=$request_id ORDER BY name ASC;", ARRAY_A);
```

and other stuff...

My problem is, that if i try to use is_admin code on in this php file, it says me that i am not admin.
In this php file doesn't work funtions like is_admin or for example get_current_user_id() will give me 0, but i am not 0... 
How can i explain Wordpress, that this php file is also his part and that he can use session of login here or something like that?

Comment: Not very familiar with wordpress but is_admin() function is located in wp-includes/load.php try including that too

Comment: Is the URL on the same domain as the wordpress server? Sounds like cookies/sessions aren't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

is_admin() indicates whether or not your on an admin page it does not validate a user role.

What your looking for is: current_user_can('administrator')

Comment: This function also doesn't work in separate php file.

Comment: Access the current user like this: `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`